# Comparing generic T objects

Tags: java, generics

I am making a generic class that utilizes T as the main parameters. I need to sort some Ts, but to do that, I need to implement a generic compareTo. I've been looking all over to find out how to do this. I know how to implement something like

```
  public class Foo implements Comparable {
       private int age;
       public Foo (int age) { 
             this.age = age;
       }
       public int compareTo(Foo a) {
             if (age < a.age) { 
                 return -1; 
             }
             if (age == a.age) {
                 return 0;
             }
             if (age > a.age) {
                 return 1;
             } else {
                 return 0; 
             }
       }
  }
```

but I'm lost when I'm trying to compare two generic objects (e.g., if T is Integer, it compares Integers, if T is String, it compares String). Basically, this:

```
  T.compareTo(T)
```

I know it's probably an easy solution that I'm overlooking, but I don't understand because there is no variable I can compare.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)? But hard to tell from your question or without at least some pseudo-code of your generic implementation.

Comment: Are you saying you've got something like `public class ThingWithComparable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<ThingWithComparable<T>>` and a field inside of type `T` that you want to compare?

Comment: If there is no variable to compare, why would you want to compare?

Comment: Basically, I made a T[] array that I'm trying to sort. I want to be able to plug in Integers and Strings into this array so I can sort them.

Comment: Any reason not to just use `Arrays.sort(myArray)`, which looks after all the messy details for you?

Comment: I cannot use it, unfortunately, or this would have been done hours ago...

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot?

Comment: Your description indicates you may need to actually implement a generic [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is an object that gets compared. Also you talk about generics but your code example is not generic so I don't understand what it has to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the generic form of `Comparable` with a generic type parameter, instead of the raw form of `Comparable` that has none.  It makes sense to compare `Foo` objects with other `Foo` objects.  I wouldn't use a generic type parameter; I would just supply `Foo` as the type parameter on `Comparable`.

Try

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
```

Then your `compareTo` method should work.

Comment: I still don't understand how I can generally compare objects that I plug in, though.

Comment: @aire `someFooReference.compareTo(someOtherFooReference)`

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm still not getting here... I'm not sure how to write the compareTo method for generics

Comment: You did write it properly already.  The generic signature of this method in `Comparable` is `compareTo(T)`, but since you supplied `Foo` for `Comparable`'s generic type parameter `T`, the proper signature for the implementation is `compareTo(Foo)`, as you already have it.

Comment: Sorry, I feel really stupid... but when I try to do 

public class Foo implements Comparable<T> 

It forces me to implement the method- and then I get to 

public int compareTo(T o) {
     return 0;
}

But there's nothing to compare!

Comment: I don't understand why you must have the generic type parameter `T` in your code.  Just implement `Comparable<Foo>`.

Comment: Well, again, I have to be able to compare generic types- I can't do something like Comparable<Integer> because I have to be able to receive Strings and compare them as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your class to be able to sort things of some arbitrary type `T`, you have two options, and you can do them both at once if you like.

```
public class Sorter {
    public static < T extends Comparable< ? super T > >
    void sort( T[] atUnsorted ) {
        // here you know that the elements of atUnsorted
        // can be compared with each other using their
        // compareTo methods
        ...
    }
    public static < T > void sort(
        T[] atUnsorted, Comparator< ? super T > cmpT
    ) {
        // here you can use cmpT.compare to compare
        // any two elements in atUnsorted
        ...
    }
}
```

If you prefer having a dedicated Sorter instance for each type `T` you can make the type parameter into a class level generic parameter and not use static methods.